# How would i change this static array to pull from this plist in xCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, plist

I have a plist located online (in format http://example.com/people.plist). How could I have the UITable View pull the names from the plist rather than the static array?

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>fname</key>
    <string>Scott</string>
    <key>sname</key>
    <string>Sherwood</string>
    <key>age</key>
    <string>30</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>fname</key>
    <string>Janet</string>
    <key>sname</key>
    <string>Smith</string>
    <key>age</key>
    <string>26</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>fname</key>
    <string>John</string>
    <key>sname</key>
    <string>Blogs</string>
    <key>age</key>
    <string>20</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Here is my **viewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


Person *p1 = [[Person alloc] initWithFname:@"Scott" sname:@"Sherwood"  age:30];
Person *p2 = [[Person alloc] initWithFname:@"Janet" sname:@"Smith"  age:26];
Person *p3 = [[Person alloc] initWithFname:@"John" sname:@"Blogs"  age:20];

self.people = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:p1,p2,p3, nil];
}
```

and here is my **tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
Person *p1 = [self.people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = p1.fname;
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to fetch the plist stored in a remote server or do you want to bundle the plist along with the app and display its contents? BTW the url of plist is not accessible

Comment: Thanks. First, right the URL is the format, not the actual URL of my plist. I added my plist so you could see. Secondly, I would like it to be online, not packaged. :)

Comment: There is a similar post in SO. I guess it would work fine for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10973246/767730

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this is in regard to writing a plist to file, which I won't need to do. Essentially I'm just wanting to pull that array from a plist. Thanks! :)

Comment: Note that this is **completely unrelated** to Xcode.

Comment: @user529758 thanks and sorry. i removed the Xcode tag. i was new and didnt know what i was using was related to xcode or objective-c exclusively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom initializer for your `Person` class and populate the array from the plist almost directly:

```
@implementation Person

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSString *fname = [dict objectForKey:@"fname"];
    NSString *sname = [dict objectForKey:@"sname"];
    NSString *age =   [dict objectForKey:@"age"  ];
    return self = [self initWithFname:fname sname:sname age:[age intValue]];
}

@end
```

And then do something like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"people" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *plist = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *item in plist) {
    Person *p = [[Person alloc] initWithDictionary:item];
    [people addObject:p];
    [p release];
}
```

And then just use `people` as the data source.

One marginal conceptual improvement: instead of storing the age as `<string>`, store it as `<integer>`. In this case, you would have `NSNumber` objects (on which you could also call the `intValue` method in the first step).

Comment: Wow. This looks to be exactly what I'm looking for. And what really helps is that you wrote out the methods instead of just saying "do a [method]." two points of clarification on my end: I'm going to get rid of age, anyway, as this is a tutorial I'm customizing to build a custom Word Dictionary app for local catch phrases, so that's ok. Second, could I replace "withContentsOfFile" with "withContentsOfURL"?

Comment: @GeoffHill Think it about a moment and try to answer yourself. Can you? If so, why? If not, why not?

Comment: Oops. No I couldn't. As "path" and "bundle" suggest it is in the package, correct? So how could I pull from online source??

Comment: @GeoffHill Wrong. You could. Why couldn't you?

Comment: ok so i can just change 
    `NSArray *plist = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];`
to
    `NSArray *plist = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:@"http://url.com/list.plist"];` ?

Comment: i dont know. im not familiar enough with it to bet any money on it :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25911/discussion-between-geoff-hill-and-h2co3)

Comment: on the line `return self = [self initWithFname:fname sname:sname age:[age intValue]];`

im getting no visible interface for 'person'. suggestions?

Comment: im also getting a few "local declaration of 'age' hides instance variable